# How to call function inside controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two functions in login controller both functions are 
     implementing login purpose ,
     In this controller **!scope.isLoggedIn** condition satistified need to check if inside condition.
      i need to permanate login in application so i store userid and password credienticals in local sessionStorage
      whenever values are available in localStorage i need to execute automaticLogin function,
      i checked localStorage data is available or not in if condition
      if both userid and password is available in localStorage i need to execute automaticLoginUser function
      if not no need to execute automaticLogin function
      whenever i am try to execute that automaticLoginUser function getting error 
      TypeError: scope.automaticLoginUser is not a function error.
      Thank you in advanced..!

```
  app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope',
        'userService', '$state', '$rootScope','BackendService', 'CartService',

        function(scope, userService, $state, rootScope, BackendService, CartService) {
            scope.user = {};
            scope.isLoggedIn = false;
            scope.userId = CartService.getuserId();
            scope.userPassword = CartService.getuserPassword();
            if (!scope.isLoggedIn) {
                console.log('in side isLoggedIn');
                if (scope.userId !== undefined && scope.userPassword !== undefined) {
                    var loginId = scope.userId;
                    var password = scope.userPassword;
                    scope.user.loginId = loginId;
                    scope.user.password = password;
                    console.log('after user' + scope.user);
                    var user = scope.user;
                    scope.automaticLoginuser(user);
                }
                scope.automaticLoginuser = function(user) {
                    alert("Inside automaticLoginuser");
                    CartService.saveuserId(scope.user.loginId);
                    CartService.saveuserPassword(scope.user.password);

                    userService.loginuser(user)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            scope.userUuid = response.data.userUuid;
                            userService.setuserUuid(scope.userUuid);

                            if (response.data.status === 'success') {
                                CartService.saveFuuid(scope.fuuid);
                                $state.go("app.userHome");
                            } else {
                                $state.go("app.login");
                            }
                        });
                };

                scope.loginuser = function(user) {
                    CartService.saveuserId(scope.user.loginId);
                    CartService.saveuserPassword(scope.user.password);

                    userService.loginuser(user)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            scope.userUuid = response.data.userUuid;
                            userService.setuserUuid(scope.userUuid);

                            if (response.data.status === 'success') {
                                $state.go("app.userHome");
                            } else {
                                $state.go("app.login");

                            }
                        });
                };
            }
        ]);
```

Comment: I think you are calling  scope.automaticLoginuser(user); before it is declared

Answer (score 3):

First I cannot overstate how ill advised it is to save a users username and password anywhere on the front end including local session storage. Hope you hashed it in some way.

Secondly, the issue you are facing is because you are trying to call scope within the controller before it is declared. This is unnecessary anyway as $scope is an instance of this which angular instantiates with the controller for you to be able to call it from the DOM.

So the correct thing will be to define the function normally since you only plan to call it in your controller.

```
function automaticLoginuser(user) {
    alert("Inside automaticLoginuser");
    CartService.saveuserId(scope.user.loginId);
    CartService.saveuserPassword(scope.user.password);

    userService.loginuser(user)
        .then(function(response) {
            scope.userUuid = response.data.userUuid;
            userService.setuserUuid(scope.userUuid);

            if (response.data.status === 'success') {
                CartService.saveFuuid(scope.fuuid);
                $state.go("app.userHome");
            } else {
                $state.go("app.login");
            }
        });
};
```

And then just call it normally

```
automaticLoginuser(user);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to **re-order** your functions.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope',
  /*'userService', '$state', '$rootScope','BackendService', 'CartService',*/

  function(scope /*, userService, $state, rootScope, BackendService, CartService*/ ) {

    scope.automaticLoginuser = function(user) {
      alert("Inside automaticLoginuser");
      /*CartService.saveuserId(scope.user.loginId);
      CartService.saveuserPassword(scope.user.password);

      userService.loginuser(user)
        .then(function(response) {
          scope.userUuid = response.data.userUuid;
          userService.setuserUuid(scope.userUuid);

          if (response.data.status === 'success') {
            CartService.saveFuuid(scope.fuuid);
            $state.go("app.userHome");
          } else {
            $state.go("app.login");
          }
        });*/
    };

    scope.loginuser = function(user) {
      /*CartService.saveuserId(scope.user.loginId);
      CartService.saveuserPassword(scope.user.password);

      userService.loginuser(user)
        .then(function(response) {
          scope.userUuid = response.data.userUuid;
          userService.setuserUuid(scope.userUuid);

          if (response.data.status === 'success') {
            $state.go("app.userHome");
          } else {
            $state.go("app.login");

          }
        });*/
    };
    scope.user = {};
    scope.isLoggedIn = false;
    scope.userId = 'admin'; //CartService.getuserId();
    scope.userPassword = 'admin'; //CartService.getuserPassword();
    if (!scope.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log('in side isLoggedIn');
      if (scope.userId !== undefined && scope.userPassword !== undefined) {
        var loginId = scope.userId;
        var password = scope.userPassword;
        scope.user.loginId = loginId;
        scope.user.password = password;
        console.log('after user' + scope.user);
        var user = scope.user;
        scope.automaticLoginuser(user);
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
</div>
```

**Controllers don't really have "constructors"** - they're typically used just like functions. But you can place initialization in your controller function and it will be executed initially, like a constructor:

```
function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.firstMethod = function() {
    //initialize the sampleArray
  };

  $scope.secondMethod = function() {
    $scope.firstMethod();
  };

  $scope.firstMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scope.automaticLoginuser` is being defined after your if statement. The first thing to do would be define the method higher up in the controller.